# Javascript functions returning function

Tags: javascript, function

Learning javascript , and had couple of questions on below code

```
const o = {
    f (v){
        function c(p){
            console.log(p)
        }
        return c
    }
}

f1 = o.f()
f2 = o.f()
```

**Questions**

1) does `f1 and f2` get different `clones of c(p)`

like `f1 and f2` each pointing to unique memory space , where `c(p)` code is copied

2) or does `f1 and f2` point to same memory space as `c(p)`

3) also is the above code a scenario of closure ?

where `o.f` has a closure on `c(p)` , and even after `o.f` execution stack is gone away we have a reference to `c(p)` in form of `f1 and f2`

Comment: 1.yes 2.no 3.yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) does f1 and f2 get different clones of c(p)

That is correct. Each call to `o.f()` creates an entirely new `function c(p)`. This is very easy to show, as well, I'll modify your code slightly:

```js
const o = {
    f (v){
        function c(p){
            console.log(p)
        }
        return c
    }
}

f1 = o.f()
f2 = o.f()

console.log(f1 === f2);
```

So, we can clearly see that `f1` and `f2` are different, thus the function returned is not the same. Just for clarity, objects in JavaScript are only equal if they are the *same* object, not just similar in shape and content. And functions are objects, as well, thus:

```js
const a = function f() {
  return 2 + 2;
};

const b = function f() {
  return 2 + 2;
};

const c = a;

console.log("a === b", a === b); //false
console.log("b === c", b === c); //false
console.log("a === c", a === c); //true
```

> 2) or does f1 and f2 point to same memory space as c(p)

Well, most definitely no. I've shown this above - functions are different.

> 3) also is the above code a scenario of closure ?

Eh, yes but...it really doesn't matter. A closure is created *every time a function is created*. So, there is one for `o.f()` itself and then one created with `c()` every time `o.f()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuitions are correct.

Do some research on the JavaScript (and, general) subject of ***"closures."***

I think it's the closest thing to "pure magick" that we see in our world of programming.  And, extremely useful sometimes.

Comment: "*I think it's the closest thing to "pure magick" that we see in our world of programming*" but **how** are closures magic? I keep seeing things written to that effect where people are apparently unable to comprehend them and...I really cannot comprehend that. I feel like people ascribe a lot more magic (or even magick) to closures as a perpetual misinformation - they are *told* closures are special and in turn tell others "there is something special with closures" yet I keep failing to see that.

Comment: thanks @Mike Robinson , also due to ```two invocations of o.f()``` and ```two execution contexts``` , does ```f1 and f2``` get a unique memory space with `c(p)` copied in there ?

Comment: @TheMaster have you seen my avatar?

Comment: @VLAZ Ha ha nice ;)